# SharePoint 5000 List View Threshold Limit Issue in CSOM

Tags: csom

I have an issue with Sharepoint CSOM when I am trying to get subfolder with the following code

```
public void LoadFolders(Folder folder, SharePointFolder sharePointFolder)
{
  Context.Load(folder.Folders);
  Context.ExecuteQuery();

  foreach (var subFolder in folder.Folders)
  {
    var subRootFolder = new SharePointFolder(sharePointFolder, subFolder);
    sharePointFolder.SubFolders.Add(subRootFolder);
  }
}
```

I get the error below when trying to load subfolders of a folder that has an itemCount of more than 5000.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at ..SharePointApi.SharepointSdkAccessMethod.LoadFolders(Folder folder, SharePointFolder sharePointFolder) in ..\..\SharePointApi\SharepointSdkAccessMethod.cs:line 435
   at ..SharePoint.ViewModels.SharePointFoldersViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<GetFolderAsync>b__0() in ..\..\ViewModels\SharePointFoldersViewModel.cs:line 183
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue or a CamlQuery that can give the same result as my function above?

Comment: What version of sharepoint do you have?

Comment: Hello Hawk, we are using SharePoint 365 online

Answer (score 0):

Check the threshold from Central Administration -> Manage Web Applications

Select the Web App -> from Ribbon Click on General Settings -> Resource Throttling

Then increase the threshold if it is still on the default value 5000

[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer does not apply to SharePoint Microsoft 365

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/web-applications-management